# Syntax error when using sudo to execute a script

Tags: bash, sudo

I encounter a problem when launching a script using sudo, though I have no problem and the script works fine without sudo.

The Line is :
`mapfile -t dataList< <( tac /tmp/result.log | grep 'Command' | cut -d" " -f1 )`
The error is "Syntax error near the unexpected symbol " < ".
The sudo command is : 
`sudo -u victor /tmp/parse.sh`

Thank you all for help...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a different shell is executing your script, one which doesn't understand the used syntax.

Your script `/tmp/parse.sh` might lack the `#!/bin/bash` (or similar) in its head line, and a different shell (root's login shell?) might be used to execute it.

This could be fixed by adding the missing `#!` line in the script header (recommended), or by calling the shell explicitly:

```
sudo -u victor bash /tmp/parse.sh
```